# Unexpected corecursive call

Tags: isabelle, coinduction, corecursion

This (trimmed out) corecursive function definition in Isabelle

```
primcorec tree :: "'form fset ⇒ 'vertex ⇒ 'preform ⇒ (('form fset × 'form), ('rule × 'preform) NatRule) dtree" where
 "tree Γ v p =
    (case undefined of Hyp h c ⇒ undefined | Reg c ⇒
    Node undefined (fimage (tree Γ v) undefined)
    )"
```

yields

```
Unexpected corecursive call in "case undefined of Reg c ⇒ Node undefined (tree Γ v |`| undefined)" at
  "case case undefined of Reg c ⇒ Node undefined (tree Γ v |`| undefined) of Node uu uua ⇒ uua"
```

but if I simplify it further to

```
primcorec tree :: "'form fset ⇒ 'vertex ⇒ 'preform ⇒ (('form fset × 'form), ('rule × 'preform) NatRule) dtree" where
   "tree Γ v p =
      (Node undefined (fimage (tree Γ v) undefined))"
```

it works.

I also tried to use the deconstructor view, i.e.

```
primcorec tree :: "'form fset ⇒ 'vertex ⇒ 'preform ⇒ (('form fset × 'form), ('rule × 'preform) NatRule) dtree" where
 "cont (tree Γ v p) = (case undefined of Hyp h c ⇒ undefined | Reg c ⇒ (fimage (tree Γ v) undefined))"
```

And now I get a different error message: `` Invalid map function at   "case undefined of Reg c ⇒ tree Γ v |`| undefined" ``.

What might be the cause?

With other `case` expressions it works, and I don’t find any mention of a restriction in the documentation (§ 5.1.1 in the datatype documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

Via private communication I was told that the solution is to add the `(discs_sel)` option to the `datatype` wher the `Hyp` constructor comes from.